# Aritchie userdialogs no background for ShowSuccess and ShowError on iOS

Tags: ios, plugins, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have installed Aritchie userdialogs version 5 and I'm using Xamarin.Forms Version 2.2.
When I use UserDialogs.Instance.ShowSuccess or UserDialogs.Instance.ShowError, on Android a dark backgroud is displayed, on iOS is NOT displayed which makes this alert message pretty unreadable when the page behind is mostly white.
On iOS I just get the message and the icon in the center of the screen but no dark background.

Example code on iOS:
UserDialogs.Instance.ShowSuccess("Data saved correctly");

How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Without and With `ForceiOS6LookAndFeel`:

[image]

#### In your iOS native app:

- Add the Nuget `BTProgressHUD`
- In your: AppDelegate (`AppDelegate.cs`):

  - add the using clause: `using BigTed;`
  - add the code `BTProgressHUD.ForceiOS6LookAndFeel = true;` in `FinishedLaunching` method
- All done :-)

---

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    BTProgressHUD.ForceiOS6LookAndFeel = true;

    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

    LoadApplication(new App());

    return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}
```

#### Any calls within your `Xamarin.Forms` based code to `ShowSuccess` (or any other `BTProgressHud` dependent code) will default to 'older' style.

Comment: Ok, I try to force iOS 6 look and feel, but am I going to lose something else with this old look and feel ?
Is the BTProgressHUD and additional plug in which works with Aritchie userdialogs or does it replace it ?

Comment: @Stefano `Arc UserDialogs` is a wrapper for `BTProgressHud` on `iOS`, so no you will not lose anything from `Arc UserDialogs`. Just the style of the the `BTProgressHud` display will be set doing this. Give it a go, one nuget and two lines of code, if you do not like the display style, you can remove it...

Comment: TBH the "old look and feel" is just its black, it really has nothing to do with the iOS version, apart from the UIAlerts being white in iOS 7> but this isnt a UIAlert, so I would say you would get away with it especially if its on a white background..

Comment: I works fine!! Ok, I used it in this way. Thank you!!

Comment: @Stefano Great to hear!... Happy Xammie coding

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to use a Toast instead? As you can set the background like so:

```
ToastConfig.SuccessBackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.BurlyWood;
```

create it like so:

```
Toast(ToastEvent.Success)
```

Either that or you are going to have to change the BTProgressHud settings that `Acr.UserDialogs` uses. I managed it by setting these values in `Acr.UserDialogs.iOS` `UserDialogsImpl.cs`:

```
public override void ShowSuccess(string message, int timeoutMillis)
{
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        BTProgressHUD.ForceiOS6LookAndFeel = true; // This is the line you need
        BTProgressHUD.ShowSuccessWithStatus(message, timeoutMillis);
    });
}
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: FYI: You can just set that `ForceiOS6LookAndFeel` in your iOS app and it is a global change and thus your calls from your Forms code will get the older style without mod'ing the Acr UseDialog code (see my answer)

Comment: The problem with the latest version is that Toast is now displayed on the top of the screen just after iOS status bar and it's a sliding donw rectangle where I can set the backgound color. It might be ok for iOS but I have problems on Android as it cut messages longer than screen width.
I liked the quick messages as on your screen shot which has the icon as well

Comment: Damn, sorry not used to forms or Acr.UserDialogs. But I have used BTProgressHUD alot tho.